# Big Query exports

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export some data from Big Query.
This is done by first saving the table and then exporting it to google cloud storage.
This used to work just fine but recently apparently some tables have nested schemas so exporting as csv does not work anymore. Exporting as a JSON should work, and the export job claims to succeed, but data is not available on google cloud storage.
Anyone experiencing similar issues? Is Google having some problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide JobId for the export job which claims to succeed but no files created so Google can investigate

Comment: Job ID is bquijob_27c77663_15747a8ba12

Comment: job id needs to be qualified by project name (or id) where it ran to be able to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a 5GB limit on the buckets in google cloud which prevented us from exporting our datasets. Pity that the job doesn't just fail with an outofstorage error.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can either export them as JSON or flatten the nested fields.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference) the official documentation or this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135410/flattening-nested-hierarchies-in-bigquery) on the matter

Did it work?